# setPreviewTexture failed when taking second photo with Camera2

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to configure a camera compatibility without preview but after taking second photo the app crashes with exception:

> 2018-12-27 14:36:20.392 12389-12977/com.example.android.braillefeeder E/RequestThread-0: Received device exception during capture call: 
>       java.io.IOException: setPreviewTexture failed
>           at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewTexture(Native Method)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.doJpegCapturePrepare(RequestThreadManager.java:298)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager$5.handleMessage(RequestThreadManager.java:830)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

I have this code:

I'm targeting for 28 SDK version. I thought the problem may have something with thread so I tried to initialize thread in main but with no success.

```
public class CameraService {

// Size of taken photo
private static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 1280;
private static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 960;

private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession mCameraCaptureSession;

private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
private Handler backgroundHandler;

private ImageReader mImageReader;

private CameraService() {
}

private static class InstanceHolder {
    private static CameraService sCameraService = new CameraService();
}

public static CameraService getInstance() {
    return InstanceHolder.sCameraService;
}

public void initializeCamera(Context context,
                             ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener) {

    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    String[] camIds = {};
    try {
        camIds = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if( camIds.length < 1) {
        Log.e("CameraService", "Camera not available.");
        return;
    }

    startBackgroundThread();

    mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);

    try {
        cameraManager.openCamera(camIds[0], mStateCallback, backgroundHandler);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
    backgroundThread.start();
    backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
}

private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        backgroundThread.join();
        backgroundThread = null;
        backgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
};

public void takePicture() {
    Log.d("CameraService", "takePicture()");
    if( mCameraDevice == null) {
        Log.d("CameraService", "Cannot take picture. Camera device is null.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        if( mCameraDevice == null) {
                            Log.e("mStateCallback", " mStateCallbackCaptureSession configured");
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.d("CameraService", "imageCapture()");
                        mCameraCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        imageCapture();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        Log.e("mStateCallback", "Configure failed");
                    }
                }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void imageCapture() {
    Log.d("CameraService", "imageCapture()");
    try {
        final CaptureRequest.Builder builder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        builder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
        mCameraCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCameraCaptureSession.capture(builder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e("imagecapture()", "KOKOTKO");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback =
        new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureStarted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
                super.onCaptureProgressed(session, request, partialResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                if( session != null) {
                     session.close();
                }
            }
};

public void shutdown() {
    Log.d("CameraService", "shutdown()");
    if( mCameraDevice != null) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
    }
    if( mCameraCaptureSession != null) {
        mCameraCaptureSession.close();
    }
    stopBackgroundThread();
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your device (or is it the *emulator*?), albeit running Android Oreo, has a LEGACY camera. Which means, it only pretends to provide **camera2** API. The [wrapper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/camera2/legacy/) works reasonably well in standard scenarios, but cannot be used for tricky ones. You can try to work with the *deprecated* Camera API directly to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with camera2 Api in second time capture image. That problem cause you not close image `image.close` in image reader listener after get bytes;

I hope this help

Comment: I'm closing it in Main func in ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()